# Force validation on textboxfor before submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a field that is required:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
[StringLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 80 characters.")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters can be used.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am using jqueryval.

My textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.mymodel.Name , new
                        {
                            id = "namebx",
                            style = "width: 100%;",
                            @class = "form-control loginTextBoxes"
                        })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.experience.Name , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I have a control that when pressed scrolls the page to next section:

```
<div id="namebutton" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Next</div>
```

I would like that if the validation criteria is not reached the validation warning will show and the scroll will not work until valid:

```
$("#namebutton").click(function() {        
        if ($('#namebx').valid()){                
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.form-group').find('.parentDiv:hidden:first').offset().top + 500 }, 1000);
            $(".parentDiv:hidden:first").show("slow");
            alert("true");
        }             
        else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
```

At the moment all I get regardless of textbox content is an alert true and the page scrolls. The validation only kicks in when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: make sure you have referenced the jquery validation libraries and also the unobtrusive one

Comment: Hi Manish, when I click the submit button the validation works, the message appears and the textbox border changes color

Comment: You were right ... I was not referencing the unobtrusive file ... thank you